# Scatterplot with error bars

Tags: r, plot

I currently have a substantial data set and have created a scatterplot which looks into the relationship between territory perimeter and path complexity (tortuosity), using the code:

```
plot(Tortuosity~Perimeter, data=TR, xlab="Territory perimeter (m)", ylab="Path tortuosity",pch=19,cex.lab=0.85,cex.axis=0.85,cex=0.85)
```

The `TR` dataframe consists of the following information, where Prm. represents perimeter and T. represents Tortuosity

```
Prm.    T.
198.58  0.45
198.58  0.63
198.58  0.24
198.58  0.32
198.58  0.6
198.58  0.49
134.62  0.3
134.62  0.39
134.62  0.12
134.62  0.09
134.62  0.25
134.62  0.45
134.62  0.44
134.62  0.84
128.07  1.99
144.32  0.72
144.32  1.01
144.32  1.09
144.32  1.15
189.96  0.55
189.96  0.76
189.96  0.78
113.74  0.67
113.74  0.73
113.74  0.69
113.74  0.61
134.15  0.39
134.15  0.26
134.15  1.37
156.11  1.1
156.11  0.67
156.11  0.98
88.41   1.09
88.41   0.87
88.41   0.47
88.41   0.8
88.41   0.52
86.71   1.47
94.4    0.92
94.4    1.23
94.4    0.96
94.4    0.56
94.4    0.82
87.53   1.22
10.85   
93.22   1.67
90.13   1.26
90.13   0.67
198.58  1.46
198.58  0.99
198.58  0.68
198.58  0.53
134.62  0.12
134.62  0.32
134.62  0.73
134.62  1.18
144.32  1.03
189.96  0.86
189.96  0.43
189.96  0.42
113.74  0.9
113.74  0.7
134.15  0.97
156.11  0.85
156.11  0.45
156.11  0.84
156.11  0.8
88.41   0.81
88.41   1.74
88.41   0.98
88.41   0.75
86.71   1.1
94.4    0.69
94.4    0.63
94.4    0.67
94.4    0.59
94.4    0.82
87.53   0.64
87.53   0.7
10.85   2.73
10.85   
10.85   2.73
10.85   0.85
10.85   1.01
93.22   1.67
90.13   0.89
90.13   0.74
90.13   0.59
90.13   0.58
90.13   1.14
90.13   0.93
154.33  0.97
154.33  0.53
154.33  0.62
```

However I want to add standard error 'whiskers' to each point (see below for the graph).
[image]

Is there a way of doing this automatically, similar to the `lineplot.CI()` function for interactive effect graphs? Apologies for the length of information but I am not sure what will be exactly of use..

Comment: Are you only looking for a base R implementation or are other packages like `ggplot2` valid?

Comment: For examples of error bars in `ggplot2` see [the documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_errorbar.html)

Comment: I was hoping to stick to the base R implementation, but I am open to other packages. The method from ggplot2 seems to involve working out the SEs for each point, as there are so many is there a way of doing it automatically?

Comment: Please consider including a *small* [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can better understand and more easily answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it using `ggplot2` but I have to say that the plot is not very readable with the error bars included. Anyway, the manual effort is not high to produce the bars.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

TR %>% 
  group_by(Prm.) %>%
  mutate(sd = sd(T.)) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = Prm., y = T.)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = T. - sd, ymax = T. + sd), width = 2)
```

[image: plot]